# installing silverlight toolkit for windows phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, toolkit

I just downloaded the silverlight toolbox of nov11 at http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888 in order to be able to use ListPicker in my windows phone 7 application. I installed it and then started visual studio 2010 for windows phone but when I try to use ListPicker, it seems like this is not available. 
what do I need to do in order to install the toolkit so that I can use its features?

thx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit` by right clicking the References folder in the solution tree. Than on the Silverlight page you want to use the toolkit on you will need to add a reference to the toolkit assembly:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

and then you can use it like that:

`<toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="410" />`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading it you can also use the Nuget manager to add the toolkit to your project: http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-install-Windows-Phone-Toolkit-Aug-2011-via-NuGet