# WPToolkit control are not showing in the ToolBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, wptoolkit

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.0 App in VS2012

And i installed the **WPToolkit Package** in the **NuGet** Manager

the package **installed successfully** and It was added to the **References**

But the controls of the package are not Showing in the ToolBox

And i also checked the **Object Browser** , All the controls were found and included by the project

but in the ToolBox they don't appear (Checked the ToolBox items too , don't appear)

What is the problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Toolkit doesn't get displayed in the toolbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824291/wpf-toolkit-doesnt-get-displayed-in-the-toolbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to add the xaml namespace to the page in which you want to use the toolkit controls. [Here is one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761945/installing-silverlight-toolkit-for-windows-phone)

Comment: I did that , now i can use the controls in the XAML code , but i cant drag them from the Toolbox , because they don't appear there

Comment: They won't appear there because you added the toolkit library to your project, so visual studio cannot find Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll in the toolbox panel and you can't drag them from the Toolbox.

Comment: So is there anyway to put them in the Toolbox ?

Comment: No we can't, while trying to add the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll in the toolbox, it will give you an error like "There are no controls in Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll that can be placed in the toolbox"